# Why zk/etcd over rdbms for cluster coordination

Tags: mysql, postgresql, rdbms, apache-zookeeper, etcd

What's the advantage of zk/etcd over rdbms such as mysql/pgsql for cluster coordination?

HA: rdbms nowadays has synchronous transparent failover with witness.

Distributed system can scale horizontally better, but I don't think cluster coordination for stuff such as hadoop/kubernetes/etc have that high volume of throughout or data size requirement.

So eh... What does zk/etcd offer for cluster coordination that traditional rdbms cannot fulfill?

Answer (score 3):

Automatic leader election is the reason. `etcd` and other consensus systems implement consensus algorithms like [Raft](http://raft.github.io/) or PAXOS so that in the face of individual machine failures a cluster of machines can figure out what to do next without human intervention. People use this as a way of implementing safe distributed locks that are immune to machine failure and split-brain scenarios.

Here is an animation of etcd recovering from two machine failures including the leader: https://speakerdeck.com/philips/coreos-plus-kubernetes-at-all-things-open?slide=55

Comment: Well, most rdbms have automatic fail over too?